# Como fazer baralhar este array dentro dele mesmo?

Tags: php

```
$img = array
  (
  array("1.jpg","Logo","Tigre"),
  array("2.jpg","Logo","Cão"),
  array("3.jpg","Logo","Montanha"),
  array("4.jpg","banner","Design Grafico"),
  array("5.jpg","Logo","Dentista"),
  array("6.jpg","Logo","Basketball")
  );
```

Queria que por exemplo o array ficasse assim

```
$img = array
  (
  array("5.jpg","Logo","Dentista"),
  array("1.jpg","Logo","Tigre"),
  array("4.jpg","banner","Design Grafico"),
  array("3.jpg","Logo","Montanha"),
  array("2.jpg","Logo","Cão"),
  array("6.jpg","Logo","Basketball")
  );
```

Tentei isto:

```
   function shuffle_assoc($list) { 
      if (!is_array($list)) return $list; 

      $keys = array_keys($list); 
      shuffle($keys); 
      $random = array(); 
      foreach ($keys as $key) { 
        $random[$key] = $list[$key]; 
      }
      return $random; 
    } 

    $img = array
      (
      array("1.jpg","Logo","Tigre"),
      array("2.jpg","Logo","Cão"),
      array("3.jpg","Logo","Montanha"),
      array("4.jpg","banner","Design Grafico"),
      array("5.jpg","Logo","Dentista"),
      array("6.jpg","Logo","Basketball")
      );
   $img = shuffle_assoc($img);
    print_r($img);
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo -1 mas eu continuo a precisar de ajuda xD

Comment: `$imagens[] = shuffle($img[0])` não faz o que você precisa?

Comment: não esta a funcionar

Comment: Queria baralhar a posição dos arrays mas mantendo a ordem de cada "linha"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pelo que notei não existe padrão algum, então usar apenas [`shuffle(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) deve resolver:

```
<?php

$img = array(
    array("1.jpg","Logo","Tigre"),
    array("2.jpg","Logo","Cão"),
    array("3.jpg","Logo","Montanha"),
    array("4.jpg","banner","Design Grafico"),
    array("5.jpg","Logo","Dentista"),
    array("6.jpg","Logo","Basketball")
);

echo 'Antes:', PHP_EOL;

var_dump($img);

shuffle($img);

echo 'Depois:', PHP_EOL;

var_dump($img);
```

Veja o resultado no [ideone](http://ideone.com/tFEF4B)

Comment: +1 ... [There is no shuffle.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECQxrFYYk2g)